# Vinyl Sheet Flooring -- Underlayment?

Tags: flooring, moisture, vinyl-flooring, underlayment

I'm looking at laying down some vinyl sheet flooring in my basement. Currently it's just a concrete floor with a layer of DryLok I've painted over it.

My question/concern is, do I **need** some type of underlayment for the vinyl sheet flooring to finish this project as close to proper as possible? Such as a rubber or cork underlayment. Also, would I **need** a moisture barrier such as some 6 mil plastic sheeting? I've not noticed any moisture from the floors. But I guess I should test that.

On-to the want portion of this. Assuming I don't **need** anything in the previous paragraph, I'd **want** this floor to have some cushion so it's closer to actual wood(or is that just a dumb idea I've got and there's no way I can accomplish that). Is there something out there that I can lay down, such as this rubber layment: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Leggett-Platt-100-sq-ft-Premium-1-3-mm-Flooring-Underlayment/1002799344 -- will the vinyl sheet flooring stick to this with adhesive? Sounds silly when I type it out, but, want to make sure before I go and purchase everything

Seems like for the vinyl peel and stick planks you'd need an underlayment. But can't find anything for the vinyl sheeting.

Comment: The vinyl sheet should have instructions on what to use.  It is thin flooring so you do want a very smooth floor under it, even something as thin as a dime under it will cause damage in a few weeks.